# Race conditions with setTimeout in a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, race-condition

What happens when I call setTimeout in a firefox extension?  Is there ever a condition in which multiple callbacks can run simultaneously?

My firefox extension contains an array of URLs that I want to take screenshots of.  My extension opens 5 tabs, and sets the URLs of these tabs to be the first 5 URLs in the array.  Once a page finishes loading in tab N, I want to wait 30 seconds, take a screenshot, and then pop the next URL off the array and load it in tab N.  The process repeats itself until the list of URLs is empty.

How can I be sure that each URL is processed exactly once?  If I was writing this in java I would just synchronize all accesses to my URL list.  How can I achieve this in a Firefox extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is completely single-threaded (except for the new Workers feature, which is separate).

No two callbacks can ever run simultaneously.

Comment: Is this true for javascript running in the browser chrome?  I am running privileged javascript, as part of a firefox extension.  The code isn't running inside any particular tab, and it isn't part of any HTML document.

Comment: @Rob: I'm reasonably certain that it is.

Comment: @sdwilsh: Do you have a reference?

Comment: @sdwilsh: does the single-thread rule apply for XMLHttpRequest too?  If I do multiple send calls asynchronously, will more than one go out at a time, or will they queue as well?

Comment: @Rob: The requests will be sent in parallel, but the callbacks will be executed in sequence on the UI thread.

Comment: @SLaks no, but it's the same JS engine, so it has the same constraints (just more APIs available to it).